# Get user in the form

Tags: python, django, django-2.1

**I have a model**

```
class someModel(models.Model):
    .....
    .....
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #User is the field that I need from the form
    .....
    .....
```

Here I have fields that have to be filled and the user field that is connected to the users table

**In my forms**

```
class someForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = someModel
    fields = [....., 'user']
    widgets = {  ....  }
```

I want to pass the user from my view but I don't know how to do that and I cant find it online. Form fails because the user is not passed.

```
@login_required
def someView(request):
    organisator= request.user
    if request.method == "POST":

        cl_form = SomeModel(data=request.POST, initial={'user': organisator})


        if cl_form.is_valid():
            cl_form.save(commit=True)

        else:
            print(cl_form.errors)

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('someviewfromurls'))

    else:
        cl_form = someForm(initial={'user':organisator})
        return render(request, 'somefile.html', context= 
   {"cl_form": cl_form})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
if cl_form.is_valid():
    instance = cl_form.save(commit=False)
    instance.user = request.user
    instance.save()
```

Comment: Tried that and similar stuff but it didn't work. I ended up creating new form class with forms.Form not the model and adding user onto the model object later after getting the data with post request.